# How to restore my database .bak file in client's Sqlexpress while installing setup?

Tags: sql-server-express, setup-project, database-restore

I am developing my own database enabled software and thus creating setup and deployment file to enable the client/user of my system to install my software. I want to embed sql express database instance to get installed when they install my software into their system.

The main thing is that I want that the user do not any database related activity, that is, they should just install software and ready to do their business. They need not be concerned with database connection, script running and other database related tasks.

I want to embed database installation logic from within setup and deployment project.

Answer (score 0):

If there is no data (or only a small amount of data) in the database to be created, the better option may be in your installation logic install the express instance, then run a script to create the database and tables etc and insert any default data that there may be into it as part of your application installer.  This should also result in a smaller installation package as you won't need to include a .bak file in the installer, just a couple of script files.